# Pass a variable between multiple several functions | Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

thanks for reading this post. I want to make an advanced TicTacToe game with AI and other stuff. I need to pass the spots(s1-s9) variable between different functions. I have been researching for quite a bit now, and I would like to meet an answer. Here is part of the code I need to execute:

```
def set_spots(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9):
    return s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9

def print_spots():

    print('\n')
    print(str(s1) + ' | ' + str(s2) + ' | ' + str(s3))
    print('--+---+--')
    print(str(s4) + ' | ' + str(s5) + ' | ' + str(s6))
    print('--+---+--')
    print(str(s7) + ' | ' + str(s8) + ' | ' + str(s9))

def game_loop():

    set_spots(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    print_spots()

game_loop()
```

I want to be able to set the spots in any function like if I had a turnX function. Like if I had:

```
def turnx(): #This isnt in this code though
    #if stuff == other stuff (just example):
        set_spots('X','O',3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

But the output is:

```
NameError: name 's1' is not defined
```

So basically, I need the program to ask the user where their x or o would be placed on the board (which you don't have to worry about) then have that value stored to be printed out. Like if I change 1 to X in the game, it needs to be stored so it can be printed out.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you should try using the variables from set spots, on print spots:

```
def print_spots(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9):
    return s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9):

    print('\n')
    print(str(s1) + ' | ' + str(s2) + ' | ' + str(s3))
    print('--+---+--')
    print(str(s4) + ' | ' + str(s5) + ' | ' + str(s6))
    print('--+---+--')
    print(str(s7) + ' | ' + str(s8) + ' | ' + str(s9))

def game_loop():

    print_spots(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    print_spots()

game_loop()
```

if that doesen't work then i'm not sure

Comment: That wouldnt make sense because you cant type code after a return statement

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the need of the unnecessary `set_spots()` function.
All you need is an array:

```
def turnx(s):
    if 1 == 1: # (a condition):
        s = ['X','O',3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  
    return s

def print_spots(s):
    print('\n')
    print(str(s[0]) + ' | ' + str(s[1]) + ' | ' + str(s[2]))
    print('--+---+--')
    print(str(s[3]) + ' | ' + str(s[4]) + ' | ' + str(s[5]))
    print('--+---+--')
    print(str(s[6]) + ' | ' + str(s[7]) + ' | ' + str(s[8]))

def game_loop():
    spots = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] # Use an array
    print_spots(spots)
    spots = turnx(spots)
    print_spots(spots)

game_loop()
```

This outputs:

```
1 | 2 | 3
--+---+--
4 | 5 | 6
--+---+--
7 | 8 | 9


X | O | 3
--+---+--
4 | 5 | 6
--+---+--
7 | 8 | 9
```

Answer (score -1):

do yourself a favor and represent the spots as a list.  Then store that list in a variable when you call set spots and pass it on to print:

```
def set_spots(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9):
    return [s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9]

def print_spots( spots ):
    s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9 = spots

    print('\n')
    print(str(s1) + ' | ' + str(s2) + ' | ' + str(s3))
    print('--+---+--')
    print(str(s4) + ' | ' + str(s5) + ' | ' + str(s6))
    print('--+---+--')
    print(str(s7) + ' | ' + str(s8) + ' | ' + str(s9))

def game_loop():

    spots = set_spots(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    print_spots(spots )

game_loop()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering I will look at it later I have to go at the moment.